# LINE python library can't login

Tags: python, authentication, line

According to http://carpedm20.github.io/line/tutorial.html,

but I try , always get exception then I type pinCode in mobile

then authToken = client.authToken , get another error

I stuck in here,this is test information below:

```
>>> from line import LineClient
>>> client = LineClient("xxxxx@xxxx","xxxx")
Enter PinCode '4169' to your mobile phone in 2 minutes
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "line/client.py", line 79, in __init__
self.login()
File "line/api.py", line 98, in login
raise Exception("Code is removed because of the request of LINE corporation")
Exception: Code is removed because of the request of LINE corporation
>>> authToken = client.authToken
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'client' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned at http://carpedm20.github.io/line/tutorial.html as,

> You will failed to login because of the request of LINE corporation. (I have to remove some codes) However, you can use this library by login with authToken. The instruction about authToken login is explained in bellow paragraphs.

it is not possible to login LINE with email and password. The related codes are deleted because of the request of LINE corporation.

You need to get your own *authToken* from your LINE client and I cannot tell you how to get it.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same error as you, not being able to login via email and password. After a series of commands in mingw32 MSYS Shell, I managed to get my session key and send a message to my contacts via Python Shell.

Solution:

1) You need Python2. Make sure your PATH environment system variable points to `C:\Python27; C:\Python27\Scripts`

2) You need to download Apache Thrift (Python2 is supported, not Python3)

3) Download the MingGW Installation Manager .exe setup. In the basic setup pane, select only "mingw-development-toolkit" and "msys-base" and apply changes. In the all packages pane, install additional packages "msys-rxvt", "msys-unzip", "msys-wget", "msys-zip" (only the 4 binary ones) and apply changes.

4) Create shortcut on Desktop. Set the location to `C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\msys.bat`, and call it MSYS Shell. Right-click on the new shortcut    and open its properties. Edit it so it looks like this: Target: `C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\msys.bat --rxvt`. Start in: `C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin`. Press the OK button.

5) Now launch MSYS shell and type the following in: (this is to fix the login with email and password error, you can copy the commands here and paste in the shell using "Shift + left mouse click". (You can also use Git Bash instead of MSYS shell for the commands.)

```
$ pip install line && pip uninstall -y line
$ git clone https://github.com/carpedm20/LINE.git
$ cd LINE/line
$ wget https://gist.github.com/windows98SE/b739038218b6fe4d423f/raw/5f68cf3d9a2a88576b739810a6bd6fcaa0c5e940/api.py.patch --no-check-certificate
$ patch api.py < api.py.patch
$ cd ..
$ python config.py
$ python setup.py install
```

6) Try to relogin using your email and password in Python Shell and print out the authentication token. You should be able to see your token and see your profile contacts and send messages to them via Python Shell.